# Windows phone 8.1 Edge multiselect like Outlook

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8.1, multi-select, listviewitem

I'm working on a windows phone application that has a Pivot and a listView. I would like to add editing for each item and multiselect to disable / delete certain items in the list. I would like the multi-select to work similar to the Outlook or messaging application on the phone. I'm having a hard time finding a way to add the "edge" tap on the upper left to enable multi-select.

Does anyone have any knowledge of is this is possible with the listview or if there is something else I should be looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's very much possible, but not really out of the box.

There is a great blog post called [MultiSelectListView with Edge Action](https://modernography.wordpress.com/2014/08/28/multiselectlistview_with_edge_action/) which demonstrates how to do exactly what you want with the ListView!

Comment: Awesome. I had found this, but thought maybe by now it might be out of the box. I didn't want to use someone else's code for this if I didn't have to. Maybe I can take parts of it. Thanks again!